# How to play a lane against tristana?

Tags: league-of-legends

I always lose when I am against a tristana, never won a single lane against her.

Fact is that I find her not predictable: she just farms and gets harrassed by me, then she decides that it is enough, so jump+E first kill.

No matter how much I harrass her, my impression is that I am under her control and I die when she decides to...

Comment: Poke her when she comes in, don't overcommit, win in mid game. Explosive shot makes her csing a bit more difficult

Comment: This is kind of a broad question since there are tons of other factors that can add to this. Do you try to 1v1 duel tristana (this is not a good idea as tristana is one of the best duelist adc's)? Are you a passive laner (sit back and don't force waves)? What is your support doing? What is their support doing? Who do you typically play as an adc? Do you use ignite, heal, or barrier? Are you fighting her when she has a full wave with her? These are just a few things to keep in mind. I also find that its much easier to fight her provided she doesn't hit you with her rocket jump.

Comment: Please clarify - are you seeing Tristana played as a marksman in bottom lane, or as an assassin (building AP) in mid? My answer & the previous commentors have presumed bottom lane marksman.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to learn a champion's weaknesses is to play that champion until someone beats you. That will show you how it is done.

This is not always an accessible solution - most recent champions cost a lot of IP. But in this case, Tristana is very cheap and there is a permanent promotion which will unlock her + a skin for free.

Writing speculatively, rocket jump has less base damage than explosive shot, but gains 5 more damage per rank than explosive shot does & deals damage up front, so the all-in style of Tristana play likely prioritizes ranks in jump. This means that anything which allows you to get out from under the jump and avoid its damage will save you from death. Rocket jump's animation is long enough to permit reacting with flash, but that has a much longer cooldown than rocket jump. Champions Ezreal, Lucian & Corki have their own move skills which act quickly enough to get you out. Caitlyn also has a move block but there's a windup animation, which may prevent you from getting out in time to avoid the impact damage.

Comment: This kind of reverse engineering I like. +1

Comment: Cait's move is fast enough, I like going Cait vs a Trist, since Cait's range is higher till late game, so you can harass Trist early on and almost always hinder her ability to jump and win the trade off.

Comment: I would have to disagree with the first line of your answer. Playing the champ doesn't do a lot, its good to learn the abilities of the champ faster but thats about it. Playing the champ does not mean you are going to be good with them, you could be beaten by X champ that your a counter to... this would give the impression that X champ is good to play against the champ you want to counter. Overall this wouldn't be good for you so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Good answer. I would just add that communication with the jungler should also be key, since Tristana tends to push her lane due to explosive shot. Winning lane also has a lot to do with map/lane awareness, in my opinion.